# How to enable a second dropdownlist when a textbox has data and dropdownlist is selected?

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2015, drop-down-menu, textbox

I have a textbox #Email and I have two dropped down list menus that is #Carriers and #Phones. When the Email is entered I want to enable only Carriers drop box but not the Phones. When the Carriers is selected the Phones dropdownlist has to be enabled. The Phones dropdownlist can only be enabled when there is an email and carriers selected. If user enters email and selects an item from #carriers and #phones and then email is erased the two drop menus have to be disabled. Is there a way that I can do a compound sentence? Below is the working Carriers when email is entered.

```
          $(document).ready(function () { //Will check for e-mail and enable #Phones dropdownlist, otherwise, it will disable dropdownlist of #Phones
             $('#Email').on('input change', function () { //check to see if email textbox is empty
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $('#Phones').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else {
            $('#Phones').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Need this to included #Phones && #Carriers

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {//need this to enable when email and carriers is selected. 
    $('#Email').on('input change', function () { //check to see if email is empty
          if ($(this).val() == '') {
            $('#Phones').prop('disabled', true);
          }
        else {
            $('#Phones').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#Email').on('input change', function () { //check to see if email is empty
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        $('#Carriers').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#Phones').prop('disabled', true);
      }
    else {
        $('#Carriers').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

This will enable Carriers when you change Email but will disable both Carriers and Phones if you delete it.

```
$('#Carriers').change(function () { 
      if ($('#Carriers').val() == '') {
        $('#Phones').prop('disabled', true);
      }
    else {
        $('#Phones').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

and this will enable Phones when you change Carriers. You are already checking E-mail at first action and disable Carriers if there is no value so you don't need to do this again here.

Comment: Hmmm.. I used the bottom statement but when I erase the email address the #Carries disables but not the #Phones. The way it works right now, user enters email and #carriers enables, user selects an item in the #carriers and #phones enables. When I erase #email the #carriers disables but the #phones is still enabled.

Comment: Edited my answer. Added '#Email' to second function. Can you check this now.

Comment: The way I want it to work is when user selects items from #carriers and #phones and then deletes email both drop down menus have to be disabled. Right now the #Carriers only disables and not the #phones.

Comment: Okey deleted Email check from second event and added Phones to first events if block. Now this has to check both phones and carriers when you delete Email. Can you try this now please

Comment: The way you have it above?

Comment: Yes it's updated. First event is about both Carriers and Phones now so if you delete email, it will disable both of them but when you enter any Email, it will only enable Carriers.

Second event is only check Carriers to enable Phones now.

Comment: That works! I tested all the possibilities! Thank you! :)

Comment: I was wondering if you knew how to set the drop down boxes back to default?

Comment: what do you mean by default?

Comment: You answered my question correctly. However, I realized that when user deleted email address the drop down boxes would block but it still showed what user selected. By default I meant "select a carrier" and "select and phone." The only thing I added to the code was  $(this).val($(this).find("option:first").val()); This sets the drop down boxes to default. Future reference.

Comment: Do you happen to know any bootstrap?

Comment: Nope but you can ask and try me